# Определить в поле формы пользователя при загрузке страницы

Tags: python, django

Необходимо определить в поле формы пользователя при загрузке страницы
Пробовал сделать и на фронте

```html
<form action="{% url 'worklist' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" id="id_username" value="{{User.user}}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.namework.id_for_label }}">Название</label> {{form.namework}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.datework.id_for_label  }}">Дата </label> {{form.datework}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.timework.id_for_label  }}">Время </label> {{form.timework}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.aboutwork.id_for_label  }}">Описание </label> {{form.aboutwork}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ form.tagswork.id_for_label  }}">Теги </label> {{form.tagswork}}
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить дело</button>
</form>
```

Или добавлять в функцию во вьюхе, не получается и таким способом

```js
def add_work(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
  form = WorkForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
  form.save(commit = False)
form.username = request.user
form.save()
else :
  form = WorkForm()

listtodo = Worklist.objects.all()

context = {
  'listtodo': listtodo,
  'form': form,
}
return render(request, 'listorg/worklist.html', context)
```

файл forms.py

```js
class WorkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tagswork = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tags.objects.all(), empty_label=" Выберите тег ")

    class Meta:
        model = Worklist
        fields = ('namework', 'datework','timework', 'aboutwork', 'tagswork')

        widgets = {
            "datework": DateInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form=control',
                'type': 'date',
            }),
            "timework": TimeInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form=control',
                'type': 'time',
            }),
            "aboutwork": Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form=control',
                'rows': 2,
            }),
            
        }
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="id_username" value="{{ user.username }}">